# The uniqueness of a set that contains a given simply-connected set and has the smallest perimeter

Tags: convex-analysis, euclidean-geometry

Suppose $A$ is a simply connected set in ${\mathbb R}^n$. I'm trying to show a set $H$ which satisfies $A \subset H$ and has the smallest perimeter among supersets of $A$ is the convex hull of $A$. However, I couldn't even show that such $H$ is uniquely defined, i.e., the number of sets $H$ which satisfies above conditions is exactly one.

If $H$ forms a polygon, then we may show that by using the triangle inequality, but if $H$'s closure is a curve, how can I show that? Is it possible to divide the curve infinitesimally and adopt the inequality again?

I'm sorry my lack of basic mathematics knowledge and the resulting naive question. Thank you.

Comment: What you really want to do here is draw some pictures of very wiggly sets A I think :)  The point is that the shortest distance between two points in Euclidean space is a straight line, so given any two points in $A$ if the straight line between them does *not* lie in $A$ as well then you can replace some section of the perimeter of $A$ by part of that straight line.  This new set must be closer to $H$ than $A$.  Keep doing this iteratively and you will end up with a convex set $H$ that is *a* convex hull.  Now use the fact that $H$ is the smallest such set

Comment: @postmortes Thank you for kind answer! I understood the method. Actually, if we construct $H$ by the method, $H$ must be determined uniquely. However could I ask more naive question? I wonder if there exists other ways which do not depend on the concrete construction.

Comment: @postmortes For instance, if there are sets $H, H'$ whose perimeters are the same and the smallest among that of sets containing the given set $A$. Could we show $H = H'$ directly from these conditions? Sorry...

Comment: Which shapes are allowed for $H$? If the shape is weird, then how to define its perimeter?

Comment: @PaulFrost Indeed it is a point I don't understand, sorry. I have not studied measure theory, so I cannot figure out the rigorous definition... At first, let me assume that $H$ has a 'smooth' closure or $H$ is partially polygon. ($H$ is surrounded by an almost everywhere differentiable curve, I'm not confident, sorry.)